# Check if a value is available in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose I have a JSON as follows

```
[{"skill":"java"},{"skill","js"},{"skill","jquery"}]
```

I need to find if the entered skill is available in JSON

```
function checkSearchQuery(query){
    $.getJSON('assets/static/json/keywords.json',function(data){
        $.each(data, function() {  
            if(query.toLowerCase() == this.skill.toLowerCase()) { 
                return true; 
            } 
         });
     });
}
```

I am checking like this

```
if(checkSearchQuery("Java")) {
       // Do the action
}
else {
       // Do else part
}
```

But this seems to execute the else part always.

Comment: checkSearchQuery is an async call

Comment: It's always evaluating the `else` block because `checkSearchQuery()` isn't actually `return`ing anything. Since `$.getJSON()` is asynchronous, the `return` statement is evaluated after the `if`. The `return` is also within `function(data){...}` and will apply to that function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are making an asynchronous call within `checkSearchQuery()`, the if condition will be evaluated before the function ever returns.  You need to understand this and either do your work in the success handler, or utilize the deferred object using something like `done()`. For example:

```
$.getJSON('assets/static/json/keywords.json',function(data){
    $.each(data, function() {  
        if(query.toLowerCase() == this.skill.toLowerCase()) { 
            return true; 
        } 
     });
 }).done(function(..)) {
     // perform some action
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.getJSON` works async, you should send a callback function,

```
function checkSearchQuery(query, callback){
    var result = false;
    $.getJSON('assets/static/json/keywords.json',function(data){
        $.each(data, function() {  
            if(query.toLowerCase() == this.skill.toLowerCase()) { 
              result = true;  
            } 
         });
         callback(result);
     });
}

checkSearchQuery("Java", function(result) {
  if (result == true) {
    //do the action
  } else {
    //do else part.
  }
});
```